# Form calculations, only first field works

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to sum all prices and multiply them with quantity. Problem is that only first field calculates good, others take price value of first. Help please
This is were I came for now:

```js
$('.orderForm__item').on('input', function() {
  var totalSum = 0;
  $('.quantity, .price').each(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).val();
    var price = $('.price').attr('value');

    if ($.isNumeric(quantity)) {
      totalSum += parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    }
  });
  $('#total').text(totalSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" class="orderForm">
  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="1.70">(1.70 KM)</span><br>
  </div>

  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="3">(3.0 KM)</span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="15">(15 KM)</span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="1.7">(1.70 KM)</span><br>
  </div>
</form>
Total: <output id="total"></output>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `each` for `orderForm__item` and find `quantity`, `price` per item:

```js
$('.orderForm__item').on('input', function() {
  var totalSum = 0;
  $('.orderForm__item').each(function() {
    var quantity = $(this).find('.quantity').val();
    var price = $(this).find('.price').attr('value');

    if ($.isNumeric(quantity)) {
      totalSum += parseFloat(quantity) * parseFloat(price);
    }
  });
  $('#total').text(totalSum);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form" class="orderForm">
  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="1.70">(1.70 KM)</span><br>
  </div>

  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="3">(3.0 KM)</span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="15">(15 KM)</span><br>
  </div>
  <div class="orderForm__item">
    <label>Item</label>
    <input min="0" max="99" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" /><br>
    <span class="price" value="1.7">(1.70 KM)</span><br>
  </div>
</form>
Total: <output id="total"></output>
```